# Mysql determine max char_length of a column including headers

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if there is a query that can give me the max character length of the data in a column as well as the headers for the column. I'm currently using:

```
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH("column")) FROM table
```

This command does what I want for the most part, but it doesn't include the lengths for the column headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By header do you mean the column name? You can just compare it to the name of the column as a string. The `GREATEST()` function takes a variable number of arguments, and returns the argument with the greatest value.

```
SELECT GREATEST(CHAR_LENGTH('column'), MAX(CHAR_LENGTH("column"))) FROM table
```